# How to be the owner of all files created by someone else on my Google Drive company account

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have multiple freelancers working on my company and using our Google Drive. But every time that I stop working with someone and I revoke their access to my Google Drive, I lose the files they created while working with me...

So I want to know if there's a way where I can add someone to my google drive, and every file they create will belong to my company instead their personal account.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "I revoke their access to my Google Drive"? Have you assigned an account from your company to the freelancers? What Google Workspace edition do your company have?